# CSS Grid. Выравнивание по центру

Tags: html, css

не работают свойства выравнивания для блока(stats_info).

```css
.stats {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #211b19, #4e3427);
}

.stats_info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
}

.stats_item span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="stats">
  <div class="stats_info">
    <div class="stats_item">
      <img src="img/clients.png">
      <span class="stats_count">3587</span>
      <p class="stats_text">satisfied clients</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stats_item">
      <img src="img/cups.png">
      <span class="stats_count">207</span>
      <p class="stats_text">cups of coffee</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stats_item">
      <img src="img/posts.png">
      <span class="stats_count">2500</span>
      <p class="stats_text">blog posts</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stats_item">
      <img src="img/likes.png">
      <span class="stats_count">873</span>
      <p class="stats_text">likes</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stats_item">
      <img src="img/launches.png">
      <span class="stats_count">900</span>
      <p class="stats_text">we launched</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: К grid тоже вообще-то

Comment: @Dias, можешь показать где написано, что justify-content применяется только к flex-контейнерам??

Comment: @Dias На будущее, justify-content применяется и к Гридам тоже

Comment: @Dias, вот почитай, для общего развития...   https://tuhub.ru/posts/css-grid-complete-guide#prop-display

Comment: @ГригорийКалашников, Вопрос надо задавать так, что бы не возникало новых вопросов. `не работают свойства выравнивания для блока(stats_info).`, о каком выравнивании идет речь, по оси `X или Y`, людям гадать, что бы тебе помочь? Тут нет ясновидящих и гадалок

Comment: Ок. Речь идет о выравнивании по центру, то есть и по x и по y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в .stats_info: `height: 100%; align-content: center;`

```css
.stats {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #211b19, #4e3427);
}

.stats_info {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.stats_item span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="stats">
  <div class="stats_info">
    <div class="stats_item">
      <img src="img/clients.png">
      <span class="stats_count">3587</span>
      <p class="stats_text">satisfied clients</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stats_item">
      <img src="img/cups.png">
      <span class="stats_count">207</span>
      <p class="stats_text">cups of coffee</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stats_item">
      <img src="img/posts.png">
      <span class="stats_count">2500</span>
      <p class="stats_text">blog posts</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stats_item">
      <img src="img/likes.png">
      <span class="stats_count">873</span>
      <p class="stats_text">likes</p>
    </div>
    <div class="stats_item">
      <img src="img/launches.png">
      <span class="stats_count">900</span>
      <p class="stats_text">we launched</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```